# How to use jquery add remove class in mvc3 action link?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to add class for selected menu using jquery stuff. I tried the following method,its not working.

And my code is

```
<div class="paragraph">
   <ul class="tablinkss">
        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Login", "LogOn")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And my jquery

```
$(function () {
           $('ul.tablinkss li').click(function () {
               $('ul.tablinkss li').removeClass("active");
               $(this).addClass("active");
           });
       });
```

Thanks,

Comment: this should work, are you sure jquery is loaded correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` returns a hyperlink that will have the browser load a new page.  **JavaScript will not work in this case unless you are preventing the link from loading the next page.**  Well, it will work for a split second then the browser will show the new page.

1. Login is active.
2. The user clicks Register.
3. Register becomes active due to your JavaScript.
4. The browser loads the register page.
5. Login is active once again.

You need to fix this in your Razor template and not in JavaScript.

Comment: @Hexxagonal- Thanks  For your response. Exactly same above you list it. How can i fix this in Razor template?

Comment: That's a trickier question because many named routes can resolve to Login or Register.  I would recommend having something in ViewData or your model that specifies what is active.

Comment: @user10489 You need to create the hyperlink yourself then do a `preventDefault()` on the event args in your click handler. Your click handler currently doesn't pass in event args.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('ul.tablinkss li').on('click',function () {
           $('ul.tablinkss li').removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(function () {
   $('ul.tablinkss li').click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation()
       $('ul.tablinkss li').removeClass("active");
       $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```